# Excel exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC from ChartArea.Copy()

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm working on a C# Application thats interacts with an Excel instance using excel interop.dll v11.0.
I'm using the following code to copy a chart from the excel worksheet to the clipboard:

```
public Image ReadChart(Chart chartAccess) {
    try {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets[chartAccess.Sheet.Name];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject chart = sheet.ChartObjects(chartAccess.Name);
        chart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy();  // exception gets thrown here 
        return System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
    } catch (COMException) {
        // display error dialog etc...
    }
```

This worked fine with Excel 2007. However since switching to Excel 2013 the function ChartArea.Copy() results in the following COMExceptions being thrown:

```
Message:      "Dimension not valid for chart type"
Stack Trace:  System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartArea.Copy()

Message:      "HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
Stack Trace:  System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartArea.Copy()
```

This only happens with excel sheets of the old .xls format, xlsm / xlsx files work fine.
Using newer versions of interop.dll (v14.0 and v15.0) didn't help.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I resolved the Problem using the following workaround:

```
// ...
chart.Chart.activate();
chart.Chart.Export(filename, "PNG", false);
using (Stream reader = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
    image = Image.fromStream(stream);
}
return image;
```

Comment: That's ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS, so likely doesn't add anything to the first exception. Since it says dimensions, I'd suggest look at the values of the ChartArea properties e.g. Height and Width to see what's happening in both cases, and as a long-shot maybe try ChartArea.Select() before you .Copy()?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.copy(v=office.14).aspx) for Copy shows that there is a difference between versions 2003 and 2010.

2003:

```
void Copy(
    [In, Optional] object Before, 
    [In, Optional] object After
);
```

2010:

```
void Copy(
    Object Before,
    Object After
)
```

As you can see, the arguments were optional in 2003, and mandatory in later version.

Answer (score 0):

chart.Chart.ChartArea.Cut(); **instead of copy you can use cut it wont give any exception**