# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HRESULT : 0x800A03EC ObjectCharts Paste

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have this code

```
targetSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                        Excel.ChartObject myChart1 = targetSheet.ChartObjects("mco");       
                        myChart1.Copy();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange shape2 = sld.Shapes.Paste();

                        Excel.Worksheet targetSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                        Excel.ChartObject myChart2 = targetSheet2.ChartObjects("txAnnul");
                        myChart2.Copy();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange shape3 = sld.Shapes.Paste();

                        Excel.Worksheet targetSheet3 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                        Excel.ChartObject myChart3 = targetSheet3.ChartObjects("perceived");
                        myChart3.Copy();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange shape4 = sld.Shapes.Paste();
```

When I take only the two first charts it works fine and i have my two charts in my pptx, but when I add the third one "myChart3" I'm getting the error I mentionned in this topic title. 
Any idea of how can I sovle this please? Thank You

Comment: This this question appropriate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396451/excel-exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-from-chartarea-copy?rq=1

Comment: Actually, it's the same error message, but in his post, he's getting the error using an export image, me I'm having the error when I try to do a copy paste of a chart... And he said that we don't have the problem when we use xlsx files, my file have the xlsx extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, by using :
`myChart1.Chart.ChartArea.Copy();`  istead of 
`myChart1.Copy();`. I don't know what really happens, but i will investigate to find what's the difference between a chart.copy() and chart.chartarea.copy().
Hope that this solution can help peoples which are facing the same problem.